# Can we add conditions to the output of a deep neural network?

Tags: nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, icd

I am currently working on a clinical NER tagging application (CliNER - Clinical Named Entity Recognition system) and I am using a Bi-Directional LSTM built with Keras / Tensorflow backend for this task.

I want to know whether there is any method for adding a condition to the output.

```
For E.X. if the previous output was B-Medicine my next should definitely
I-Medicine or Other and not some random tag like B-Body-Part.
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of conditions do you have in mind? Like give example.

Comment: what do you mean by "previous output"? Is this a seq-2-seq model? If yes, the answer is yes, but you need to be more clear.